# Unit distance graphs with large minimum degree

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Inspired by [this (now closed) question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/427891/97426), I was wondering the following: What is the smallest possible cardinality of a set $P$ of points in the plane such that

- no three points in $P$ are collinear,
- for every $p\in P$ there are least $k$ elements of $P$ at unit distance from $p$.

Note that this is equivalent to asking for a [unit distance graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_distance_graph) with minimum degree $k$, but with the additional condition the there should be a representation of the graph by points in the plane with no collinear triples.

As pointed out in [one of the answers](https://mathoverflow.net/a/427902/97426) to the question linked above, the minimal solution for $k=3$ contains $6$ points (even without the restriction on collinear triples).

For general $k$, an easy solution with $2^k$ points is given by taking $k$ unit vectors, and then taking all linear combinations of these vectors with coefficients in $\{0,1\}$ (if points coincide or there are collinearities, slightly change the angles of the unit vectors). This can be improved to approximately $3^{k/2}$ many points by taking unit vectors in pairs such that the angle between the vectors in each pair is $\pi/3$.

**Question 1:** Are there solutions with a sub-exponential number of points?

**Question 2:** Does the answer change if we drop the condition of having no collinear triples?

These questions are potentially very difficult, since they seem to be related to the maximum possible number of edges in a unit distance which is an unsolved problem posed by Erdős in 1946. The following relaxation (which is also in the spirit of the [question which inspired this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/427891/97426)) is perhaps easier to answer.

**Question 3:** Are there solutions with a sub-exponential number of points if instead of unit distances we require that for every $p \in P$ there is some $d_p \in \mathbb R$ such that there are at least $k$ vertices in $P$ which are at distance $d_p$ from $p$?

Comment: If you take the grid with $n^{1+c/\log\log n}$ unit distances (Erdős 1946), then the minimum degree is the average degree (up to a constant factor), so it will be $k=n^{c/\log\log n}$, which gives something sub-exponential, no?

Comment: @domotorp: Yes, you're right - more generally, any graph with large average degree has a subgraph with large minimum degree (for suitable notions of large), so my Question 2 is equivalent to finding a unit distance graph with many edges. Any idea how to get rid of collinear triples?

Comment: I think that the best known construction gives $n\sqrt{\log n}$ unit distances for general position point sets, see Theorem 2 here: https://personal.lse.ac.uk/swanepoe/swanepoel-valtr-unitdistance.pdf